# check how many checkboxes are checked with classname?

Tags: javascript

I have found this accepted answer but somehow it doesn't work for me:

```
var checkedValue = null; 
var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('messageCheckbox');
for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
      if(inputElements[i].checked){
           checkedValue = inputElements[i].value;
           break;
      }
}
```

when I tried to log inputElements[0] it logs:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2" class="todo-checkbox" onclick="handleCheck('text-2', 'checkbox-2')">
```

I only want to use pure js, no jquery, help?

Comment: @i am gpbaculio Can you explain more clearly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the count of all checked checkbox you can use `filter()` like the following way:

```js
var inputElements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.messageCheckbox'));
var checkedValue = inputElements.filter(chk => chk.checked).length;

console.log(checkedValue);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="messageCheckbox" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="messageCheckbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="messageCheckbox" checked>
```

Comment: is this not working anymore? i click run code snippet and run your code, and the result is wrong.. in snippet code it doesn't change at all.. in my code it change but with wrong number..

Comment: @HidayatRiva'i, of course the the above code snippet is working accordingly. There are 2 checked check boxes and shows 2 in console. What you are getting?

Comment: it's works on my localhost now.. thank you.. but it's error when i click run code snippet.. the number doesn't change at all.. maybe it just my browser, i dont know..

Answer (score 1):

**give name attribute to all the checkbox and use this code to count the checked checkbox**

```
$('input:checkbox[name=ideaList]:checked').length
```

**if you want to get the value of checked checkbox the take a vatiable and push the checked checkbox value in that variable**

```
var selectedIdeas    = [];
$.each($("input:checkbox[name=ideaList]:checked"), function(){
     selectedIdeas.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: *I only want to use pure js, no jquery, help?*

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="todo-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="todo-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="todo-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="todo-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="todo-checkbox">
```

select all the checkboxes and then use a forEach loop to count which of those are checked

```
function countChecked(){
  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.todo-checkbox')
  let count=0
  checkboxes.forEach(checkbox=>{
    if(checkbox.checked) count+=1
  })
  return count
}
```

you can play with the codes [here](https://codepen.io/prithweeDas/pen/LaybLz)

and for when you log inputElements[i] you are getting the node itself, `document.getElementsByClassName`, `document.querySelectorAll`, etc, these return a `NodeList` not a JavaScript Array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, You want to Check how many checkboxes are checked using Classname:

Alerting your code a bit,

```
var checkedBoxCount =0;
var inputElements = document.getElementByClassName(`your_classname`);
for(var i=0; i<inputElements.length; i++){
  if(inputElements[i].checked){
    checkBoxCount++;
  }
}

console.log(checkedBoxCount); //returns total count of checkboxes being checked
```

If you want to get the checked checkboxes then,

```
var checkedBoxes =[];
var inputElements = document.getElementByClassName(`your_classname`);
for(var i=0; i<inputElements.length; i++){
  if(inputElements[i].checked){
    checkBoxes.push(inputElements[i])
  }
}

console.log(checkedBoxes); //returns the checked check boxes
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope This will help you , Pure JS no jquery.

```js
function countCheckbox() {
 var count=0;
 var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
 for(var i in checkboxes){
        if(checkboxes[i].checked)count++; 
 }
 console.log('COUNT:',count);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
<button onclick="countCheckbox();">CLICK</button>
```